# Recursive Function to Print a Decision Tree in Python: Suppress 'None's

Tags: python, printing, decision-tree

I decision trees implemented in Python as dictionaries.  Example:

```
sampletree = {'spl':'foo', 'go_r':{'cut':150} ,  'l':{'val':100}, 'r':{'val':200}}
```

I have a recursive function prints the tree:

```
def TREE_PRINT(tree, indent=''):
    #is this a leaf node?
    if 'val' in tree:
        print str(tree['val'])
    else:
        #print the criteria
        print 'split: '+ str(tree['spl']) + ' ' + str(tree['go_r'])
        #print the branches
        print indent+'L->', TREE_PRINT(tree['l'], indent+'  ')
        print indent+'R->', TREE_PRINT(tree['r'], indent+'  ')
```

How do I suppress the None's that are printed when I run the function?

```
TREE_PRINT(sampletree)
split: foo {'cut': 150}
L-> 100
None
R-> 200
None
```

I tried returning '', but then I get line unwanted extra line breaks.
I'm building off of the 'printtree' function from page 151 in Programming Collective Intelligence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of your function is None. Don't print the return value of your function - just call your function.

```
def TREE_PRINT(tree, indent=''):
    #is this a leaf node?
    if 'val' in tree:
        print str(tree['val'])
    else:
        #print the criteria
        print 'split: '+ str(tree['spl']) + ' ' + str(tree['go_r'])
        #print the branches
        print indent+'L->',
        TREE_PRINT(tree['l'], indent+'  ')

        print indent+'R->',
        TREE_PRINT(tree['r'], indent+'  ')
```

Result

```
split: foo {'cut': 150}
L-> 100
R-> 200
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/ALizd)

Comment: Thanks!  The comma was confusing me - I had never used that syntax before. I'll accept as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide if `TREE_PRINT` prints the string representation or returns it. If you mean that it should print the data, then what you want your code to be is:

```
def TREE_PRINT(tree, indent=''):
    #is this a leaf node?
    if 'val' in tree:
        print str(tree['val'])
    else:
        #print the criteria
        print 'split: '+ str(tree['spl']) + ' ' + str(tree['go_r'])
        #print the branches
        print indent+'L->',
        TREE_PRINT(tree['l'], indent+'  ')
        print indent+'R->',
        TREE_PRINT(tree['r'], indent+'  ')
```